# document.getElementsByClassName() class identifier changes

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementsbyclassname

I have a script that inserts an iFrame in a UI of one of the tools from Google. Recently there was an update and this particular tool has a new look.

I noticed that the class name changes each time I create new list and it goes like this,

**First list**,

Class Name 1: `header _ngcontent-CREATIVES-69`

Class Name 2: `_ngcontent-CREATIVES-71`

**Second list**,

Class Name 1:`header _ngcontent-CREATIVES-68`

Class Name 2: `_ngcontent-CREATIVES-70`

How do I get my script to work in order to only recognise it this way?

Class Name 1:`header _ngcontent-CREATIVES-XX`

Class Name 2: `_ngcontent-CREATIVES-XX`

The script that I've worked on,

```
var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest,
RespJSON=null;

function setvalues(t){
  ifrm=document.createElement("iframe"),
  ifrm.setAttribute("style","margin-top: -240px;width: 100%;height: 450px;"),
  ifrm.setAttribute("scrolling","no"),
  ifrm.src="#"+escape(t),
  document.getElementsByClassName("header _ngcontent-CREATIVES-69")[0].append(ifrm)
}
xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  4==this.readyState&&200==this.status&&setvalues(RespJSON=xhttp.responseText)
},

xhttp.open("GET",document.getElementsByClassName("_ngcontent-CREATIVES-71")[0].src,!0),
xhttp.send();
```

What's a good way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` to select the DOM elements with attribute selectors

`document.querySelector("[class^=\"header _ngcontent-CREATIVES-\"]").append(ifrm)`

This will select the first DOM element with class starts with `header _ngcontent-CREATIVES-`

OR

`document.querySelectorAll("[class^=\"header _ngcontent-CREATIVES-\"]")[0].append(ifrm)`

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ydz69kwp/